# Recurring Toasts with Windows 8.1 Store Apps build with JS

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I've been trying to create notifications that happen on a weekly basis - for example, every monday at 8am.

I've tried to use a recurring toast for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465417.aspx - but realized that the recurrence parameters are more designed for a snooze functionality, with a maximum delay of 60 minutes, and a maximum repeat for 3 times.

Is there a suggested workaround for this?

Is there a best practice for such a use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the recurrence on scheduled toasts is designed for snooze. Unfortunately, the API doesn't provide a way to show the same toast multiple times on a fixed schedule.

You'll need to manually create a `ScheduledToastNotification` each time you want it to be shown. In your example, you might create and schedule out a toast a week for each Monday at 8 AM.

Comment: This is the solution we ended up going with.